# Setting spark driver memory on EMR Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

We have an EMR cluster. A team used to submit pyspark commands via jupyter notebook. They recently mentioned that spark driver memory is not assigned correctly as defined in the environment variables. When I checked inside the Executors of the spark history server, it is set to 3.4 GiB as in the image below.
I checked the following files (/etc/spark/conf/spark_defaults.conf, /etc/jupyter/conf/config.json) in the EMR cluster and the `spark.driver.memory` is set to 6g. Any ideas what might be the issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html#executors-tab and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview:

```
The Storage Memory column shows the amount of memory used and reserved for caching data.
```

Storage memory is defined by `spark.memory.storageFraction` (default 0.5) property.

For the actual driver memory, you can check the value of `spark.driver.memory` under `Environment` tab in SHS UI. If it is different than the value specified in `spark-defaults.conf`, then the client might be specifying it when creating SparkSession.